# Submitting query from the autocomplete list without having to hit the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have tried to take the example given in W3Schools on Autocomplete, and have the value from the autocomplete (suggestion) list that gets placed - from the list - into the text area of the input, and automatically is submitted, this without having to hit the send button.  We see this and almost every major search engine.  You start typing your query, the suggestion box drops down, you choose your word, and it automatically gets put into the text area of the input box, then gets submitted, without you having to press submit. I believe I am missing a function, or another piece of code goes in between here:

```
b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                                                                /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                                                                inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                                                                /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                                                                 (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                                                                closeAllLists();
                                                                });
                                             a.appendChild(b);
```

I have researched this problem, and possible solutions like adding e.submit(), or where I added

```
b.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
                                                                                 if ("search_form_input_homepage").val() !== '') {
                                                            e.submit();
```

below to the function (I also changed preventDefault to e.submit)

```
                        function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
                        /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
                         the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
                        var currentFocus;
                        /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
                        inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
                                             var a, b, i, val = this.value;
                                             /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
                                             closeAllLists();
                                             if (!val) { return false;}
                                             currentFocus = -1;
                                             /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
                                             a = document.createElement("DIV");
                                             a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                                             a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
                                             /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
                                             this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
                                             /*for each item in the array...*/
                                             for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                             /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
                                             if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                                             /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
                                             b = document.createElement("DIV");
                                             /*make the matching letters bold:*/
                                             b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                                             b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                                             /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
                                             b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                                             /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
                                             b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                                                                /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                                                                inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                                                                (e).submit();
                                                                /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                                                                 (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                                                                closeAllLists();
                                                                /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/

                                                                b.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
                                                                                     if ("search_form_input_homepage").val() !== '') {
                                                                e.submit();
                                                                }
                                                                };
                                                                })
                                             ;
                                             a.appendChild(b);
                                             }
                                             }
                                             });
                                             /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
                                             inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                                                                  var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                                                                  if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
                                                                  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                                                                  /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
                                                                   increase the currentFocus variable:*/
                                                                  currentFocus++;
                                                                  /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
                                                                  addActive(x);
                                                                  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
                                                                  /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
                                                                   decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
                                                                  currentFocus--;
                                                                  /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
                                                                  addActive(x);
                                                                  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                                                  /*If the ENTER key is pressed, allow the form to be submitted,*/
                                                                  e.submit();
                                                                  if (currentFocus > -1) {
                                                                  /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
                                                                  if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
                                                                  }
                                                                  }
                                                                  });
                                                                  function addActive(x) {
                                                                      /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
                                                                      if (!x) return false;
                                                                      /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
                                                                      removeActive(x);
                                                                      if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
                                                                      if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
                                                                      /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
                                                                      x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
                                                                  }
                                                                  function removeActive(x) {
                                                                      /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
                                                                      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                                                          x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                                  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
                                                                      /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
                                                                       except the one passed as an argument:*/
                                                                      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
                                                                      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                                                          if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                                                                              x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
                                                                          }
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                                  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
                                                                  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                                                                                 …
```

Comment: Here is the link to the W3Schools autocomplete script [link] (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) `autocomplete script`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did here:

1. Give the form an id eg `myForm`
2. Replace `(e).submit();` with
   `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;  
}

.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
</style>
</head>     

<body>

<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<form autocomplete="off" id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great, can you approve my answer :)

Comment: I have never been here before, and I was just looking for how to do that.

Comment: there's a grey tick button next to answer, just click on that should do

Comment: Done!  Thanks, so very much! - ( );

Comment: By the way, many hours of working on this problem, and all I had to do was ask?!?  Thanks!  - One Question. One Answer. Solved!